# Having some problems with reverse movement of my Snake

Tags: java

Over the summer I wrote some code for a snake game (which works), but I am going back through it to see if I can tweak the code slightly.

The piece of code is pasted below:

```
public class Snake {
        String directionMoved;
    
        Snake() {
           directionMoved = "R"
        }
    
        processDirectionArrow (Event directionArrow) {
                if(directionArrow.data.equals("U") && !(directionMoved.equals("D"))) {
                    directionMoved = directionArrow.data;
                    processHeadDirectionCoordinate(directionMoved);
                } else if(directionArrow.data.equals("R") && !(directionMoved.equals("L"))) {
                    directionMoved = directionArrow.data;
                    processHeadDirectionCoordinate(directionMoved);
                } else if(directionArrow.data.equals("L") && !(directionMoved.equals("R"))) {
                    directionMoved = directionArrow.data;
                    processHeadDirectionCoordinate(directionMoved);
                } else if(directionArrow.data.equals("D") && !(directionMoved.equals("U"))) {
                    directionMoved = directionArrow.data;
                    processHeadDirectionCoordinate(directionMoved);
                }
            }
```

Essentially this piece of code shows that when e.g. I press the DOWN arrow on the keyboard, my snake moves down. But, also, if I accidentally press the UP arrow on my keyboard then the snake will not move back on itself and eat itself.

This piece of code works, but for some reason I cant really understand again the logic of why it works. I was wondering if you could guys could help here.

When I remove directionMoved from my code (which is just a string), the code no longer works and the snake moves back on itself. But I am not sure again why this is so. Why in this case does directionMoved influence whether my snake moves back on itself or not? It is only directionArrow.data that actually gets the data from my keyboard.

Was wondering if you guys could help me see the logic why this piece of code works when I include directionMoved as opposed to taking it away?

Comment: Note that the code you posted isn't actually valid Java code, which is weird, since you said it works. You're missing a return type for the `processDirectionArrow` method.

Comment: o yes, that is void. I forgot to add that

Answer (score 1):

`directionArrow.data.equals("U") && !(directionMoved.equals("D"))` can be translated roughly to

> 'if the user pressed "U" and the snake is not currently moving "D"'.

In other words: the "U" button press will cause the snake to move up (which is the code *inside* the if-block, which I left out), but **only if** the snake isn't currently moving downwards.

So `directionMoved` is used to remember which direction the snake is currently moving in, so that we can consider that when the user next issues a direction-change command.

On a related note: since the *body* of each of those `if` statements is the same, you can combine them to a single `if` with a longer condition:

```
String userInput = directionArrow.data;
if ((userInput.equals("U") && !directionMoved.equals("D")) ||
    (userInput.equals("R") && !directionMoved.equals("L")) || 
    (userInput.equals("L") && !directionMoved.equals("R")) || 
    (userInput.equals("D") && !directionMoved.equals("U"))) {
    directionMoved = directionArrow.data;
    processHeadDirectionCoordinate(directionMoved);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the time and your explanation! This helps.